# Pageviewer in a NestedScrollView not displaying text

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a PageViewer to display fragment's data, and whenever I put a TextView into the fragment's xml, it doesn't display when the app is being run. I put it in a NestedScrollView to put more widgets in then I could without it. I tried putting an ImageView in to see if it was removing everything but that worked fine, except it was a little laggy when changing fragments.
My code for my activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new VolleyballFragment(), "Volleyball");
    adapter.addFragment(new SoftballFragment(), "Softball");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

my fragment codes are the nearly same so I will only provide 1

```
public class VolleyballFragment extends Fragment{

public VolleyballFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_volleyball, container, false);
}
}
```

and the activity xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/softballFragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Softball" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/volleyballFragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vollyball" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you need any of the xml files or anything else please let me know.
I fallowed an older tutorial online since this is my first time using fragments and tabs, so I'm a little confused to begin with
Also sorry for the code being cut off and replaced as normal text

Comment: Can you please post your xml layout for this activity where you've `NestedScrollView` Setup?

Comment: of course I already put the xml file in for it  at least a few hours ago

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code everything else is fine but you're just missing `layout_behavior` on `NestedScrollView`.

After adding this property your code would look like this.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```